# Parsing negative numbers in financial statements

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm parsing financial documents and the objective is to break a line into 3 components. For example, I have the following line:

```
Telephone  9,000 9,000
```

and when I use this regex command:

```
regex = r"([A-Za-z ]+)(?=\d|\S).*?([\d,]+)\s([\d,]+)"
re.findall(regex, <string>)
```

and this is the output I get:

```
('Telephone ', '5,172', '1,771')
```

Now suppose I have negative numbers (they are represented by brackets in financial docs) in this financial statement:

```
string = Telephone  (9,000) (9,000)
```

How do I break it up into three groups by accounting for the brackets?
I've tried doing using `\(\*` and `\)\*` to account for zero or more brackets, but it returns `None`:

```
regex = r"([A-Za-z ]+)(?=\d|\S).*?(\(\*[\d,]+\)\.)\s(\(\*[\d,]+\)\)"
re.findall(regex, string)
```

How can I update my regex function to account for that case?

Also, if the string has a hyphen, how do I pick that up?

```
string = Telephone  (9,000) -
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/we8CvY/1/

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern works for me:

```
texts = ['Telephone  9,000 9,000',
         'Telephone  (9,000) (9,000)',
         'Telephone  (9,000) -'
         ]
for text in texts:
    print(re.findall("([\w+ ]+) (\(?[\d,-]+\)?) (\(?[\d,-]+\)?)", text))
```

**Output**

```
['Telephone', '9,000', '9,000']
['Telephone', '(9,000)', '(9,000)']
['Telephone', '(9,000)', '-']
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be quite confused about escaping brackets. Your regex has some escaped `*`s, so I don't really know what you are trying to do here.

Assuming that all inputs are well-formed (i.e. there's no missing brackets or anything like that) and you just want to extract the three values, you can use this regex:

```
([A-Za-z ]+)\s+(\(?[\d,]+\)?)\s+(\(?[\d,]+\)?)
```

The first part is same as your attempt. Then it is this pattern repeated twice:

```
\s+(\(?[\d,]+\)?)
```

At the start, we first match some whitespace `\s+`, then the capture group starts. In the capture group, we first see if there are any brackets `\(?`. `?` is the quantifier to use here, because we allow 0 or 1 bracket. And then a straightforward  character class `[\d,]+` to match the number, followed by an optional closing bracket `\)?`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/m613oZ/1)